# How to add external JARs so they appear under External Libraries in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I've downloaded the Spring framework manually and am trying to add the JAR files to an empty Java project by following:

**File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies**, then clicking the + sign and adding the JAR files.

[image]

I've also tried doing the same, but under **File > Project Structure > Libraries** instead.

But nothing appears under External Libraries in the left hand project explorer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).